# API to specific Tenants does not work in wso2 AM

Tags: wso2, multi-tenant, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

In publishing in managing step we set "Available to specific Tenants " with a tenant domain list , After publishing the API specified tenants can not see the API in the API store of the specified tenant.
and tenants which are not specified for the api can generate token with their own user credential and client id ,client secret of different tenant.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Which version of APIM you are using?

Comment: i am using wso2am-1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Although API subscription can be allowed to different tenant domains, API subscribers need to login to original API store with their creditial, discover the API and subscribe.

You can refere [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Publishing+to+API+Stores#PublishingtoAPIStores-PublishingtomultipleexternalAPIstores) document for making this API visible to those external tenant stores

Comment: yes i have  configured an API to external stores, and  it is visible to the users of those stores.

Comment: Now my problem is tenants which are not subscribed the api can generate token with their own user credential and client id ,client secret of different tenant.